Mockito fails to inject when JUnit tests are run by maven
I need to run JUnit tests on my application and I'm using Mockito to mock some objects that aren't relevant to the test but are required for one reason or another. When I run tests using IntelliJ's little green arrow the test passes, but when I run with mvn test it fails.
I have a service class
package org.lit;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyService {

    @Inject
    MyOtherService otherService;
    public void doStuff() {
        otherService.doStuff();
    }

}

I have a test like this:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.lit.MyOtherService;
import org.lit.MyService;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    MyOtherService otherService;

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_doStuff() {
        System.out.println("myService is " + myService);
        System.out.println("otherService is " + otherService);
        myService.doStuff();
    }

}


When I run the test via intellij with the little green arrow the test succeeds, but when I run mvn test I get an error (full output of mvn test -e follows).
$ mvn test -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< org.lit:testing-project >-----------------------
[INFO] Building testing-project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ testing-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ testing-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ testing-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\william\Documents\testing-project\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ testing-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ testing-project ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\william\Documents\testing-project\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running MyServiceTest
myService is null
otherService is null
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec <<< FAILURE!
MyServiceTest.test_doStuff()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MyServiceTest.test_doStuff(MyServiceTest.java:26)


Results :

Failed tests:   MyServiceTest.test_doStuff()

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.009 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-20T13:46:21-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project testing-project: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\william\Documents\testing-project\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project testing-project: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\william\Documents\testing-project\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\william\Documents\testing-project\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:650)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:586)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

pom.xml, in case dependency version is a factor since I'm working with some old versions (company is in the process of updating)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.lit</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

So it seems that however the little IntelliJ green arrow works, it correctly sets up the mockito container to inject the myService and mock entityManager, but when I run mvn test it skips mockito setup and just runs the test method directly. So my question is: how do I set up mockito to work with my test when the test is run by maven? Or conversely, how do I make maven use mockito to inject objects used by tests?

Can you post entire stack trace? You have no junit5 engine in your dependencies, my guess is that maven runs your test with junit4 runner. Stack trace can confirm or disprove this guess.

@Lesiak I've edited the section where the error was and pasted the full output of mvn test -e. The surefire-report file doesn't have any additional information.

The version of the maven-surefire-plugin which is not defined in your pom file... is ancient old... you should use most recent version (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) 3.2.5.... also all other plugins are old... use more recent versions of plugins...

@Supetorus create a new exception (do not throw) and print stack trace - it should do the trick

@Lesiak https://pastebin.com/ZRWLSwSH

Define all plugins in your pom.xml most recent versions...
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.13.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipITs}</skipTests>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

for complete example https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/

Thank you! I'll also note that I had forgotten to add @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) before the test class declaration in the example. With that, the setup method is not necessary.
